# android checkbox is not checked for custom listview when listview is in scrollview

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, customization

i have implemented custom list view with check box and textviews.  It is working fine when list view is not in scroll but if the rows are increased then listviews is in scroll view  that time when i click on check box the checked mark is not staying. here is my code, Please suggest me if anything wrong in that code

```
public class ArchivedAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MessageBean> {
final ArrayList<MessageBean> updatedList = new ArrayList<MessageBean>();
private List<MessageBean> list;
private TextView officenameView, sentOnView, messageView;
public final static String MY_ACTION = "com.android.threeptalk.broadcast";
private boolean isDeleted = false;
int count = 0;
HashMap<Integer, CheckBox> checkList = new HashMap<Integer, CheckBox>();

public ArchivedAdapter(Context context, int resourseID,
        List<MessageBean> list) {
    super(context, resourseID, list);
    this.list = list;

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return list.size();
}

@Override
public MessageBean getItem(int arg0) {
    return list.get(arg0);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    return arg0;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View row = convertView;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.archievedmsgrow, parent, false);
    row.setId(position);
    Object obj = getItem(position);
    if (obj instanceof MessageBean) {
        final MessageBean message = (MessageBean) obj;
        CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) row.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
        officenameView = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.officename);
        sentOnView = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.time);
        messageView = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.message);
        officenameView.setText(message.getOfficeName());
        checkList.put(position, checkBox);
        checkBox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                CheckBox c = (CheckBox) v;
                if (c.isChecked()) {
                    c.setChecked(true);
                    count++;
                    updatedList.add(message);


                } else {
                    c.setChecked(false);
                    count--;
                    updatedList.remove(message);
                    updatedList.size());
                }
                checkedCount(count, updatedList);
            }
        });

        row.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                rowclicked(message, position);

            }
        });
        sentOnView.setText(Common.getAppropriateTimeUsingTimeZone(message
                .getmDate()));
        if (message.getMessage() != null) {

            messageView.setText((message.getMessage()));

        } else {
            if (message.getMessageType().equals("OPTION")) {
                if (message.getOptions() != null
                        && message.getOptions().size() > 0) {
                    String data = message.getOptions().get(0);
                    if (data != null && !data.equals("")) {

                        messageView.setText(data);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
    return row;
}

protected void messageSelected() {

}


protected void rowclicked(MessageBean message, int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

protected void checkedCount(int count2, ArrayList<MessageBean> updatedList) {

}
}
```

`

Comment: Refer this site:http://lalit3686.blogspot.in/2012/06/today-i-am-going-to-show-how-to-deal.html

Answer (score 4):

Try this example [**ListView with CheckBox Scrolling Issue**](http://www.lalit3686.blogspot.in/2012/06/today-i-am-going-to-show-how-to-deal.html)

Answer (score 3):

Seems like you are checking the check status of checkbox inside its **onClickListener()**.

First define an [Hashmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/HashMap.html) or [SparseBooleanArray](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseBooleanArray.html) to save your selections.

```
private HashMap<Integer, Boolean> mSelection = new HashMap<Integer, Boolean>();
```

Then add the following code to your **getView()** method.

```
 CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) row.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
    checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {
            mSelection.put(position, isChecked);
        }
    });

    if (mSelection.get(position) != null) {
        if (mSelection.get(position))
            checkBox.setChecked(true);
        else
            checkBox.setChecked(false);
    }
```

Comment: Thanku puru.. my problem was resolved.. but now how can i call the checked count method. this method i am overriding in my activity class for displaying how many check boxes are checked.

Comment: Since the checkedCount method is defined inside your adaper, you can call it from your activity by using instance of your adapter . eg. mAdapter.checkedCount(). But if you want to return the number of checked values then you need to change the return type of that mathod to int and do actually return the size of your hashmap that you are using to store the selections.

Comment: when i am cliking the checkbox, if that is checked then i am increasing int value else i am decreasing, i am accesing this count in activity and displaying the count above the listview like 2 items are selected. when i unselected then 1 item is selected.

Comment: I couldnt understand your problem properly.But AFAIK, you shouldn't be using this 'counter' approach. I suggest you to implement a hashmap or better than that a SparseBooleanArray to store the selections as I've posted it in my answer.

Comment: If the answer helped you to solve your problem, please do accept or/and upvote the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, Assuming that you are using the Custom Adapter for your ListView, you will be able to set Tag for each Item inside your Adapter's getView(),

```
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    EvenViewHolder holdereven;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInfaltor.inflate(R.layout.schedule_adapter_view,
                    null);
            holdereven = new EvenViewHolder();
            holdereven.time = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.time);
            holdereven.title = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.title);
            holdereven.des = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.des);
            convertView.setTag(holdereven);

        } else {
            holdereven = (EvenViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

 static class EvenViewHolder {
    TextView time, title, des;

}
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but what is that EvenViewHolder

Comment: Evenholder is class you can declare your custom layout view here. And use that object in your getvoew